# The number of solutions $(x,y)$ of the congruence $n \equiv X^2-XY+Y^2$ (mod $p^\alpha$).

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

Is there general formula of the solutions of the congruence?
\begin{equation}
n\equiv X^2-XY+Y^2 \pmod r,
\end{equation}
where $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $r\in\Bbb N$.

If we define an arithmetic function (two variables or one variable with fixed $n$)
\begin{equation}
N(n,r):=|\{(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2:x^2-xy+y^2\equiv n\pmod r,0\leq x,y< r\}|.
\end{equation}

I know that such function is multiplicative in $r$.

I have no approach for this question. Please give me a hint to solve this problem, or let me know that related something. Thanks.

Comment: You might want $<r,$ not $\leq r?$ I don’t think it is multiplicative for $\leq r.$

Comment: When $r$ is odd, you can multiply by $4$ and get the equivalent congruence: $$(2X+Y)^2+3Y^2\equiv 4n\pmod{r}$$

Comment: It seems like you’ll want at least three separate cases, $r=p^a$ where  $p=2, p=3,$ and $p>3.$

Comment: I got a sign wrong in my above comment. Should be $(2X-Y)^2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited the inequality in the condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you. I think that there are four separate cases,  $p=2$, $p=3$, $p\equiv 1$ (mod $6$) and otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, just an answer when $r=3^a.$

When $r$ is odd, this can be multiplied by $4$ to get $$(2X-Y)^2+3Y^2\equiv 4n\pmod r$$

Then solutions to $Z^2+3Y^2\equiv 4n$ are in $1-1$ correspondence with your congruence.

If $r=3^a,$ then:

1. If $n\equiv 1\pmod 3,$ there is two solutions for every $Y, $ for $N(n,3^a)=2r$ solutions total.
2. If $n\equiv 2\pmod 3,$ then there are no solutions, so $N(n,3^a)=0.$
3. What if $n\equiv0\pmod3?$ If $a=1,$ then $N(n,3)=3.$ If $a\geq2,$ then $3\mid Z.$ Then the number of solutions is three times the number of solutions to $$3Z_1^2+Y^2\equiv 4n/3\pmod{3^{a-1}},$$ since there are three $Y$ modulo $3^{a+1}$ for every $Y$ modulo $3^{a}.$ So $N(3n,3^{a+1})=3N(n,3^a)$

So, if $r=3^a,$ $n=3^kn’,$ with $\gcd(n’,3)=1,$ then:

$$N(n,3^a)=\begin{cases}3^a&k\geq a\\2\cdot 3^a&k<a,n’\equiv 1\pmod 3\\0&k<a,n’\equiv 2\pmod 3\end{cases}$$
Not sure what to do with the case $r=2^a.$

Nor yet the case $r=p^a$ when $p>3.$